# Degree equation in Scalar curvature problem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations

For $1<p<(n+2) /(n-2)$, $n\geq 3$, $K \in C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{S}^n)$, $(0<\alpha<1),$ $(\mathbb{S}^n,g_0)$ is standard sphere, $K>0$, consider the prescribing scalar curvature problem
\begin{equation}\label{9.7}
-\Delta_{g_{0}} v+c(n) R_{0} v=c(n) K(x)|v|^{p-1} v,
\end{equation}
Where $R_{0}=n(n-1), c(n)=(n-2) / 4(n-1)$.

Let $O_1 \subset H^{1}(\mathbb{S}^n), O_{2} \subset C^{2, \alpha}(\mathbb{S}^n)$ are two bounded open sets and $O_{2} \subset O_{1}$ under the natural injection of $C^{2, \alpha}(\mathbb{S}^n)$ into $H^{1}(\mathbb{S}^n)$. Suppose also if $v \in \bar{O}_{1}$ is a solution of the above scalar curvature eqaution, then $v \in \mathrm{O}_{2}$. The question  is: whether or not the following equation hold
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname{deg}\left(v-\left(-\Delta_{g_{0}}+c(n) R_{0}\right)_{H^{1}( \mathbb{S}^n)}^{-1}\left(c(n) K|v|^{p-1} v\right), O_{1},0\right)\\&=\operatorname{deg}\left(v-\left(-\Delta_{g_{0}}+c(n) R_{0}\right)_{C^{2,\alpha}(\mathbb{S}^n)}^{-1}\left(c(n) K|v|^{p-1} v\right), O_{2}, 0\right) ?
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I guess it can be proved by bootstrap arguments to botain the $C^{2,\alpha}$ regularity using the $W^{2,p}$ theory when $p$ is large, but failed. Thanks for any help.